How to find schema changes on a SQL Server database
I have an old Entity Framework and some spaghetti code... I made some changes in the .edmx file, and clicked on generate database from schema. I don't see the changes in the database. I would like to get the last changes on the database so I can compare them to the ones I made in the .edmx file.
I have this instance of SQL Server with several databases, the changes were supposed to go to only one of the databases.
I have tried:
SELECT name, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'P' 
ORDER BY modify_date DESC

and
SELECT name, modify_date 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE type = 'U' 
ORDER BY modify_date DESC

with no success.
I was expecting to see the list of tables that were last modified, I made some changes before this that are not even shown here
